# Finding the intersecting node from two intersecting linked lists

Tags: c, algorithm, linked-list

Suppose there are two singly linked lists both of which intersect at some point and become a single linked list.

The head or start pointers of both the lists are known, but the intersecting node is not known. Also, the number of nodes in each of the list before they intersect are unknown and both list may have it different i.e. List1 may have n nodes before it reaches intersection point and List2 might have m nodes before it reaches intersection point where m and n may be

- m = n,
- m < n or
- m > n

One known or easy solution is to compare every node pointer in the first list with every other node pointer in the second list by which the matching node pointers will lead us to the intersecting node. But, the time complexity in this case will O(n<sup>2</sup>) which will be high.

What is the most efficient way of finding the intersecting node?

Comment: See also [Production code for finding junction in a linked list](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2230718/production-code-for-finding-junction-in-a-linked-list). It is not a duplicate, but it is extending the problem that is asked about here.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

This takes O(M+N) time and O(1) space, where M and N are the total length of the linked lists. Maybe inefficient if the common part is very long (i.e. M,N >> m,n)

1. Traverse the two linked list to find M and N.
2. Get back to the heads, then traverse |M − N| nodes on the longer list.
3. Now walk in lock step and compare the nodes until you found the common ones.

---

Edit: See more [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20190426202842/http://richardhartersworld.com/cri/2008/linkedlist.html).

Comment: Accepting this answer as this doesn't need modification of the list and also does not eat extra space. But, I am still wondering if there aren't any better solutions than this. Anyways, Thanks a lot for your reply and others also.

Comment: Doesn't the answer by @Jakob Borg incur one less round of iteration that calculating the difference in lengths of the two linked lists?

Comment: @user1071840: Yes, the difference is that Jakob's answer needs O(N) extra space to store the colors.

Answer (score 16):

If possible, you could add a 'color' field or similar to the nodes. Iterate over one of the lists, coloring the nodes as you go. Then iterate over the second list. As soon as you reach a node that is already colored, you have found the intersection.

Comment: This is possible only when altering the list is permitted.

Comment: Not necessarily. You can use an external array or hashtable to store colors.

Answer (score 7):

Dump the contents (or address) of both lists into one hash table.  first collision is your intersection.

Comment: If there is 2 linkedlist like 1-2-3-4-3-5 and 9-8-3-5. And the 2nd linkedlist intersect the 1st one in 2nd 3rd. But if we use some hash table then it will clash at first position of 3.

Comment: one linked list can't contain 3 twice unless it's already twisted
into a "6" instead of a linerar list.

Comment: linked lists can have repeated values, so repeated 3 is very much legal. Address collision is the correct way.

Answer (score 1):

Check  last nodes of each list, If there is an intersection their last node will be same.

Comment: The question is intended to find the intersecting node.

Answer (score 0):

This is crazy solution I found while coding late at night, it is 2x slower than accepted answer but uses a nice arithmetic hack:

```
public ListNode findIntersection(ListNode a, ListNode b) {
    if (a == null || b == null)
        return null;

    int A = a.count();
    int B = b.count();

    ListNode reversedB = b.reverse();

    // L = a elements + 1 c element + b elements
    int L = a.count();

    // restore b
    reversedB.reverse();

    // A = a + c
    // B = b + c
    // L = a + b + 1

    int cIndex = ((A+B) - (L-1)) / 2;
    return a.atIndex(A - cIndex);
}
```

We split lists at three parts: `a` this is part of the first list until start of the common part, `b` this is part of the second list until common part and `c` which is common part of two lists. We count list sizes then reverse list `b`, this will cause that when we start traversing list from `a` end we will end at `reversedB` (we will go `a -> firstElementOfC -> reversedB`). This will give us three equations that allow us to get length of common part `c`.

This is too slow for programming competitions or use in production, but I think this approach is interesting.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe irrelevant at this point, but here's my dirty recursive approach.
This takes `O(M)` time and `O(M)` space, where `M >= N` for `list_M` of length `M` and `list_N` of length `N`

1. Recursively iterate to the end of both lists, then count from the end for step `2`. Note that `list_N` will hit `null` before `list_M`, for `M > N`
2. Same lengths `M=N` intersects when `list_M != list_N && list_M.next == list_N.next`
3. Different lengths `M>N` intersects when `list_N != null`

Code Example:

```
Node yListsHelper(Node n1, Node n2, Node result) {
    if (n1 == null && n2 == null)
        return null;
    yLists(n1 == null ? n1 : n1.next, n2 == null ? n2 : n2.next, result);
    if (n1 != null && n2 != null) {
        if (n2.next == null) { // n1 > n2
            result.next = n1;
        } else if (n1.next == null) { // n1 < n2
            result.next = n2;
        } else if (n1 != n2 && n1.next == n2.next) { // n1 = n2
            result.next = n1.next; // or n2.next
        }
    }
    return result.next;
}
```