# How to find if two linked list intersect each other?

Tags: algorithm

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Finding the intersecting node from two intersecting linked lists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2216666/finding-the-intersecting-node-from-two-intersecting-linked-lists)

Given two large linked list, which

1. a) Do intersect
2. b) May intersect

   find the node that is at the intersection.  By intersection I don't mean their values. I mean a node is common. i.e. two different nodes from list A and list B point to same node

E.g.

```
3->1->2->4->NULL
      ^
      |
5->4->3

3->1->2->NULL
      ^
      |
9->2->3
```

PS :
 3. Hash tables not allowed.

4. Obvious brute force method N*M comparisons is ruled out. We want better solution.

Answer (score 6):

To find whether there's an intersection, just check whether the "ends" of both lists have the same address. But that's not strictly necessary.

Turn the first list into a loop by linking from its last node to its first[*]. Then use your favourite cycle-finding algorithm starting at the beginning of the second list, to find the cycle and its start-point. If there's no intersection, you won't find a cycle in the second list. If you do find a cycle in the second list, then the start-point of the cycle is the point of intersection.

[*] if you're allowed to modify the data, do so. Otherwise, write a "step forward" function that special-cases that particular node.

Comment: Nice answer. :) I came up with some on my own but that required three traversal and a reversal.

Answer (score 3):

if lists intersect their last nodes are the same