# Finding the merging node of two linked list?

Tags: algorithm

I have gone through this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2216666/finding-the-intersecting-node-from-two-intersecting-linked-lists) where accepted
 answer depict below algorith to find merging node

> 1) Traverse the two linked list to find M and N.
>
> 2) Get back to the heads, then traverse |M - N| nodes on the longer
>   list.
>
> 3) Now walk in lock step and compare the nodes until you found the
>   common ones.

I am not sure will it always work?  Foe example :- list 1 has 10 nodes and list 2 has 3 nodes where very first node is merging node(**so in shape letter "V" upside down**). Now if i go by above
algo,

> 1)M= 10, N=3
>
> 2)M-N will be 7
>
> 3)I pick list 1 and traverse first 7 nodes. Now i start comparing each
>   node starting from 8th node in list1 with the all the nodes of second
>   list.

Now i will never catch the merging node (which is the very first node here) . Am i missing something in my undestanding or there is some flaw in this algo?

Comment: "M-N will be 3". Shouldn't that be 7? In any case, if the very first node is the merging node, doesn't that mean the lists are completely identical?

Comment: What does this have to do with java or C, as opposed to being completely language agnostic?

Comment: @Kevin i have corrected that. But still my question is same.

Comment: @scott corrected that

Comment: The 8th node *is* the right answer here, and you only need to compare it with the 1st node in the second list.  Draw it on a piece of paper.

Comment: That is, the 8th node in list 1 is the 1st node in list 2.  (When you wrote "where very first node is merging node", you meant "Where the very first node *in list 2* is the merging node", right?  It doesn't make sense to talk about the position of a merging node without specifying which list you're referring to.)

Comment: "in shape letter "V" upside down" is impossible. Two merging lists will always form a variation of a Y shape.

Comment: Ok then looks like i misunderstood the problem. Yes in case Y this algo is perfect

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are suggesting that the first node of each list is the merging node then you have misunderstood the problem.

After the merging node both lists are identical (since that node is the same in both it must point to the same successor which must point to the same successor, etc.). The key thing this algorithm uses is the fact that from the merging node there are the same number of items between it and the end of the list.

Essentially the algorithm finds the length of the lists and then traverses to a node on the longer list that means that node and the first node of the other list have the same distance to the end. It then walks along the nodes until it finds matching ones.

In your example the 8th node is the earliest that the merging one can be found. This is because the 7th node has three nodes after it (8, 9 and 10) but the first of the other list only has two nodes after it so the 7th cannot be the merged one.

So you compare node A8 and B1, if they don't match then you compare A9 and B2, if they don't match A10 and B3 and if they don't match then there is in fact no merging node. (An means the nth node in list A in case that isn't obvious).

Answer (score 0):

after a point where two lists will merge they will be completely the same since `both of them point to the same memory` so the next item will be the same. 
if they will both start on the first node they will both be completely the same since they will point to the exact same locations in the memory, think about it, how could you tell the first list from the second? 
the only way that they will have different length is if the shorter list come in the middle of the longer one that is after the intersection they are the same. after the intersection they both have the same length.

so, in order to solve the problem we wish to make the lists in the same length, then they will have the same number of elements both before the intersection and after it.
after that is done go one step in a time to pass all the different items until we get to the same item.